# Paste Text from clipboard to Text box in focus of browser using MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, copy-paste

I have an application which copies the Email Id to clipboard in my application.
What i want to next is, When the user clicks on the textbox of the Browser(IE,Chrome,FF) And presses the paste button of my application , it should paste the contents of the clipboard in that focused TextBox. Please Note that my Application is Created in MFC, c++. I have Implemented code for copying the text to clipboard from within my application, but am wondering how will it be possible to paste the text outside my application , when the event is fired from my application. If question is not clear please comment it. Your Help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: First of al: Can you paste your data into notepad? If not you have to inspect the code that copies the data into the clipboard.

Comment: @xMRi: Yes am able to copy the data and paste it anywhere i want it. So that clears that the copy works well.

Comment: You have **copied** the text to the clipboard. Pasting does not involve your application anymore. What's the question?

Comment: I think you do not need to do this via Clipboard at all. All you need to do is just to SendMessage WM_SETTEXT to the handle of the Browser's address bar. Use spy++ to find out some basic features of the address bar control, then validate if the user's focused object is the proper one and Send the message away

Comment: @IInspectable: Cha: What i have to do ultimately is, I have to go to browser and click and get the focus to that text field. (Consider their is 3 text field one below other). Once i have done that, i have to go to my application and click paste button which will get the text copied to the clipboard and will insert that in textfield of browser(). Eg: "abcd\t defg \t hijk" this is my clipboard text. Then when i click the paste button of my application . this text should be pasted one by one in all the three textfield of the browser.Consider \t as command to get to next text field.

Comment: Getting your text into the clipboard is the easy part. And a bad idea, too. The clipboard belongs to the user - don't hijack it for your own use. The hard part is `1)` entering text into a browser's text box and `2)` finding out where to paste it. This involves automating the browser - the text box is not a native control. Your requirement about pasting to the focused control is a hard one: By the time you click your application's button, that button is focused. You have lost the information you set out to use.